# How can i receive a report error message when report error button is clicked

Tags: android-button, edittextpreference

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4GhQ.png)Good day everyone, please i am developing an Android application in android studio. The problem here is how can i receive report error message problems whenever my android app user wants to make a complain programmatically? please

Comment: You need to make your question easier to read - start by giving a name to your image. As this is your first question, I suggest that you read https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.